# OBD-II simulator tool?

Tags: open-source, simulation, iot

I am making a platform for Car diagnostic and analytics which works with TCP protocol OBD-II devices. And for this, I need data from an OBD-II device. I have one device with me but I need more of them and I can't purchase them. So I am looking for a software application(free obviously) that will simulate an OBD-II device and provide almost all types of data including location. Also, if possible we can simulate multiple devices from it.

If anyone knows any manufacturer which can provide this Please let me know.

Or is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: The devices are freely available everywhere. Eg Ebay for 5.98

Comment: @RohitGupta I don't want hardware, I want a software tool that can simulate an OBD-II device working on TCP protocol. And I want this software for free.

Comment: Yes. I know.  But you said you cant purchase them implying they werent available.

Comment: @RohitGupta - I interpreted the OP's original statement that they didn't have any budget for such things, rather than they couldn't find them to buy.

Comment: @MichaelKohne, I realise that it can be interpreted that way.  Which is why its only a comment and no down votes were involved.  :-)

Comment: @RohitGupta Michael is right, That is why I am asking for a software recommendation.